# Custom List, Searching "9" will return record with ID of 9. How do I exclude ID from search?

Tags: search, custom-list

I have anabled search on a Custom List. However, I do NOT want it to return records based on its ID #. If I type in "9", I do not want it to return a record simply because it is the ninth record.

Does anyone know how to amend this?

Comment: check this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/da9196d1-69bd-4ca9-a6cf-92587c903fcc/excluding-item-ids-from-search-scope?forum=sharepointsearchprevious

Answer (score 0):

First, find the crawled property in Search Administration

---

- On the Search Administration page, in the Quick Launch, under Queries
  and Results, click Search Schema

  On the Manage properties page click on crawled properties

---

Then *uncheck* columns which you do not want to include in search.

Follow this link for more information about crawled properties 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219667.aspx

Comment: Please note that this is a service-wide setting, and it will remove the ID from index for all lists in your farm that uses the same search service

Comment: Yes this will remove index for all the list that uses same search service.Sorry for not mentioning that